# CORS request error (react native / laravel passport)

Tags: react-native, laravel-5

I created a mobile app which consumes a back-end API.I am using fetch api on JS end to make my requests. However, I am getting a CORS error

```
Error message: Access to fetch at 'mydomain.com' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have tried the following:

A/ In my .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]]
 <FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, token"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
 </IfModule>
```

This had the effect of at least letting my GET request to pass.

B/ in my index.php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
```

Same effect as .htaccess, only GET request passes, with OPTIONS . I also saw the my Access-Control-Allow-Origin would be "*, null" and i would get an error stating that only one is allowed.

C. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors
In AuthServiceProvider, i tried both these. Only one at a time, not at the same time.

```
        Route::group([ 'middleware' => 'cors'], function() {
            Passport::routes();
        });

    Passport::routes(null, ['middleware' => [ \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class ]]);
```

D. Created a custom middle with this code

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
                return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
```

I dumped my $_SERVER and could not find the HTTP_ORIGIN, HTTP_REFERER. I did get my HTTP_REMOTE_ADDR

What is even more frustrating was that my app was working correctly, and I just suddenly started having the issue (back-end hosted on bluehost)

---

Edit: Sample request

```
var data = new FormData();

        data.append('grant_type', 'password');
        data.append('client_id', '2');
        data.append('client_secret', 'secret_token');
        data.append('scope', '*');

        data.append('username', 'mail');
        data.append('password', 'pwd');


        var link = (mydomain in https) + '/oauth/token';
        fetch(link, config)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson);

            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very weird but the issue I was having was with the config of my fetch

The initial one:

```
    const config = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + global.token,
        },
        body: data,
       }
```

The corrected one

```
    const config = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          //'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + global.token,
        },
        body: data,
       }
```

I just removed the 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',

Answer (score 0):

Append the below URL  before your request and try it.

Url to be append:
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

e.g 
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://food2fork.com/api/search?key=yourquery.

Please let me know if it works

Comment: I added a sample request. How exactly would you append?

Comment: I am still getting a 405 Method not allowed on this. But this route is clearly in the php artisan route:list

Comment: I wish I could know php, unfortunately I don't know. But thought of sharing this which might helpful in someway to you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already created a middleware, add few headers to it and list the middleware in your `protected $middleware` array in `kernel.php`and it should work. Also make sure the URL is correct.

Create a middleware cors

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*') //REPLACE STAR WITH YOUR URL
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type, authorization, x-requested-with');
    }
```

Then list the middleware in global middleware list in app/http/kernel.php

```
 protected $middleware = [
             ...
             \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class
]
```